# Width of tab character

Tags: formatting, verbatim

I'm using the `verbatim` environment to format some code.

Is there a way to set the desired number of spaces represented by a tab character?

What is the default number of spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need any further formatting of the verbatim stuff you can use the package `moreverb` or `fancyvrb`. The provided environment `verbatimtab` by `moreverb` has an optional argument to specify the width of a tab. The package `fancyvrb` provides the option `tabsize` to speficy  the width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim,moreverb,fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

package \texttt{verbatim}
\begin{verbatim*}
Hello World!
Hello   World!
\end{verbatim*}

package \texttt{moreverb}
\begin{verbatimtab}
Hello World!
Hello   World!
\end{verbatimtab}

package \texttt{fancyvrb}
\begin{Verbatim}
Hello World!
Hello   World!
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

N.b. to set the tab size in the verbatimtab environment, do the following:

```
\begin{verbatimtab}[tabsize]
```

Where `tabsize` is the number of spaces that the tab should represent.

Comment: Also `fancyvrb` allows for specifying a tab width.

Answer (score 0):

Also, take a look at `listings` and `lstautogobble`.